# TypeError: undefined is not a function on "indexOf"?

Tags: javascript, typeerror, indexof

Crawling my way through my DOM, I found this headscratcher:

I am evaluating an element with the following assignment:

```
if (e.container.context.classList.indexOf('editable-notes') == - 1) return;
```

My developer toolkit tells me this should work... I think.  But it blows up with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

...which seems odd to me.  So I put a break point in, and I examine the values.  `e.container.context` comes back as valid:

```
<td title class=​"truncate editable-notes k-edit-cell" role=​"gridcell" id=​"partner-list_active_cell" data-role=​"editable">​
<input class=​"k-textbox" data-val=​"true" data-val-length=​"The field Notes must be a string with a maximum length of 500." data-val-length-max=​"500" id=​"Notes" name=​"Notes" type=​"text" value data-bind=​"value:​Notes">​
<span class=​"field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for=​"Notes" data-valmsg-replace=​"true" style=​"display:​ none;​">​</span>​
</td>
```

...so far, so good.  `e.container.context.classList` also comes back with a valid value:

```
["truncate", "editable-notes", "k-edit-cell"]
```

...evaluation of `e.container.context.classList.indexOf('editable-notes')`, however, fails:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
message: "undefined is not a function"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

... so now I'm stumped.  I thought indexOf was pretty much universally supported.  Am I doing something dumb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classList` properties contain `DOMTokenList`s, which are not arrays and don’t have `indexOf`. What they do have is [a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList#Methods) to do exactly what you need, but more straightforwardly:

```
if (!e.container.context.classList.contains('editable-notes'))
    return;
```

Comment: SO FTW!  It looks like an array in the developer toolkit.  This works.  I will mark this as the correct answer as soon as I can.